# Build a project containing git submodules from source package of a GitHub release

Tags: git, github, build, gentoo

I want to pull a tar.gz source code package of a GitHub release and build from it. The problem is, said package doesn't contain the contents of the submodules, and it isn't a full git repository, so I can't just run `git submodule update --init --recursive`. How to solve that?

The context is, I wanted to write a Portage ebuild, which like many other ebuilds simply pulls a release source package from an address determined by its own version and builds it, so updates are a simple matter of bumping the package version and checking if it builds.

I could just clone the repo and checkout the tag, but this is frowned upon because this way Gentoo's mirrors can't cache the package archive and it creates more traffic, amongst other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to handle this is the manually create an archive of the source, including the sub-modules, and then host this on the Gentoo infrastructure. Alternatively, one can mirror it elsewhere if this is ebuild is added to a personal overlay.

**Resources**

- [Mirrors - Gentoo Development Guide](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/mirrors/index.html)